# Python Conectar Sql Com usuario e "token"

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Tenho uma aplicação em Flask e estou utilizando o SQLAlchemy para ter acesso ao SQL Server.

Gostaria que a conexão ao banco de dados seja feita por um usuário genérico e a senha é um "token", pensei que seria somente substituir os parâmetros mas não! E não achei(ou não soube pesquisar da forma correta) informação sobre.

Essa é a atual concection string:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Usuario:token@server/db?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
```

Comment: Está usando o [`flask-sqlalchemy`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/) também?

Comment: SIm, estou usando ele para ter acesso ao sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu realizo a conexão entre o SQLAlchemy e o MS SQL Serve com a seguinte string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""SQLAlchemy + MS SQL Server.

- {SQL Server} - SQL Server 2000.
- {SQL Native Client} - SQL Server 2005 (Também conhecido como versão 9.0).
- {SQL Server Native Client 10.0} - SQL Server 2008.
- {SQL Server Native Client 11.0} - SQL Server 2012.
- {ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server} - SQL Server 2005 ao 2014.
- {ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} - SQL Server 2005 ao 2016.
- {ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server} - SQL Server 2008 ao 2016.
- {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} - SQL Server 2008 ao 2017.
"""

from urllib.parse import quote_plus

import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Verificar se os drivers estão instalados.
# print([x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('ODBC')])
# print(pyodbc.drivers())

parametros = (
    # Driver que será utilizado na conexão
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    # IP ou nome do servidor.
    'SERVER=192.168.100.178\SQLEXPRESS;'
    # Porta
    'PORT=1433;'
    # Banco que será utilizado.
    'DATABASE=pythonSQL;'
    # Nome de usuário.
    'UID=python;'
    # Senha/Token.
    'PWD=123456')

url_db = quote_plus(parametros)

db = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % url_db)

conexao = db.connect()

# resultado = conexao.execute("select * from NomeDaTabela")
#
# for row in resultado:
#     print(row)
```

`quote_plus(parametros)` substitui espaços e outros caracteres especiais por caracteres válidos do HTML. É como se ele cria-se uma URI válida.

Fiz um teste com o `flask-sqlalchemy` e a conexão ocorreu sem problemas, porém não tenho como simular o "token" que você está utilizando como senha.

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

parametros = (
    # Driver que será utilizado na conexão
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    # IP ou nome do servidor.
    'SERVER=192.168.100.178\SQLEXPRESS;'
    # Porta
    'PORT=1433;'
    # Banco que será utilizado.
    'DATABASE=pythonSQL;'
    # Nome de usuário.
    'UID=python;'
    # Senha/Token.
    'PWD=123456')

url_db = quote_plus(parametros)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % url_db
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
# app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = ''

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Usuario(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ativo = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    nome = db.Column(db.String(50))
    idade = db.Column(db.Integer)
    sexo = db.Column(db.String(10))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Nome %r>' % self.nome


@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(Usuario.query.all())
    return 'OK'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Lembre-se de verificar se os drivers do SQL Server estão instalados. Caso não estejam

[Página de download do SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)

No Linux basta instalar os drivers adicionando o [repositório oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Para o teste utilizei as seguintes dependências (`Pipfile`):

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
flask = "*"
pyodbc = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```